# How to get Spring MVC @PathVariable without using an annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Given the spring mvc method like the one below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit")
public String processSubmit(@PathVariable("ownerId", int ownerId, 
                            @PathVariable("petId") int petid) {

}
```

Is there some way to write the method so that all the URI templates variables are passed in as a 
map to the handler? something along the lines of ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit")
public String processSubmit(Map<String,Object> allPathVariables) {
     Integer ownerId = allPathVariables.get("ownerId");
     Integer petId = allPathVariables.get("petId"); 
}
```

Is there a way to put all the URI templates in a Map that is passed to a handler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can't be done with Spring MVC 3.1 there is an issue for it on the spring JIRA which is marked fixed for Spring MVC 3.2 https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9289